# Im trying to get the mouse to move with pyautogui for an fps game bot however the code wont make the camera move

Tags: python, automation, bots, pyautogui

the mouse only moves when the cursor is unlocked eg when in menu but in match when cursor is locked the mouse aka camera is not movable with the code although it moves fine manually. Ive tried everything but I cant get it to automatically move

I first used pyautogui.moveTo but that did not work then .move() and still no success. I dont think .drag() would work since it *drags* the cursor not moves

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.